# How can I return an entire column based on the minimum of a specific row criteria?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have something like the following:

a =

```
 5     1     4
 2     1     1
 5     2     8
```

I am looking to return the minimum value of the third row

`b = min(a(3,:));`

b =

```
 2
```

How would I be able to return the entire column (i.e. (1;1;2)) and then  <strike>subtract</strike>  remove that column from the matrix?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to subtract the column with the minimum value from the whole matrix (as was initially asked) use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) like so:

```
[v, i] = min(a(3,:));
a = bsxfun(@minus, a, a(:, i));
```

UPDATE:
You can extract and eliminate the column from `a` like so:

```
[v, i] = min(a(3,:));
col = a(:, i);
a(:, i) = [];
```

Comment: Is there anyway to remove that column instead of insert zeros?

Comment: @Kelly I suggest you edit your question to say "remove" instead of "subtract", if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Could the above code be easily modified for iterations? for i=1:n, remove from a and add to col.

Comment: @Kelly Sure, but extracting the `min(a(3,:))`-column from `a` and appending (...assuming you mean append instead of add ;-) it to another matrix in a loop sounds to me like sorting the columns of `a` according to the third row. That can be done without a loop. Or do you need to change the row-index (here 3) in each loop-iteration?

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove the column, use

```
a(:,i) = [];
```

where `i` is the index of the column